# angular ng-if doesnt work inside self-built component

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm breaking my head to understand why the 'ng-if' doesnt work on the element. I know that ng-if="true" seems strange, I just wanted to emphasize that the problem is not in the expression. What am I doing wrong??

```
<div ng-init="model.class = $parent.model.setClass.next().value" class="soldier" ng-class="{ '{{model.class}}':true }" ng-if="true">
</div>
```

Here's a link to an example: https://jsfiddle.net/z38me4fq/

If you omit the 'ng-if' you'll see the directive appearing

Comment: Probably looking for a variable named `true`, which gets evaluated as falsy (then the element is removed/hidden from the DOM tree).

Answer (score 0):

I think that for some reason, ng-if creates a new child scope. So now if I want to get to the method I have to use another '$parent', in order to init the model.class property.

```
<div ng-init='model.class = $parent.$parent.setClass.next().value' class='soldier' ng-class='model.class' ng-if='true'></div>
```

Here's what I did:
    https://jsfiddle.net/z38me4fq/1/